# Barra de busqueda mas de una palabra en php

Tags: php, javascript, web

Saludos compañeros, quiero saber como puedo hacer una busqueda con mas de una palabra en el imput, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que tome estas dos palabras y hacer el query para que me retornen resultados donde se encuentren esas dos palabras.

Comment: Para que te retone resultados que contengan las dos palabras o que contenga al menos una de ellas? lo haces en base de datos? en que motor?

Comment: Que contenga al menos una de ellas. Estoy utilizando PhPmyAdmin MySql.

Comment: Podrías poner como haces tu consulta hasta el momento para poder ayudarte más orientado a tu código?

Comment: _"Estoy utilizando PhPmyAdmin MySql"_, realmente phpMyAdmin no es un motor de bases de datos, es una herramienta para administrar bases de datos MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

necesitas generar un query sql como este

```
SELECT * FROM tu_tabla WHERE nombre like '%palabra1%' OR nombre like '%palabra2%'
```

para ello debes de separar las palabras que componen tu frase, en php se hace con explode

```
$palabras=explode (' ','tu cadena original');
```

luego generas tu query iterando por las palabras

```
 $query='SELECT * FROM tu_tabla WHERE';
for ($i=0;$i<count($palabras);$i++){
   $query.=" nombre like '%".$palabras[$i]."%' ";
   if ($i<count($palabras)-1){
     $query.=" or ";
   }

}
```

te sugiero que elimines las palabras cortas y de uso común como 'el' o 'de'

Answer (score 1):

aquí te dejo una función de ***php*** que realiza la búsqueda por mas de una palabra, está la tengo probada en ***mysql***. El resultado del ***string***  que te da solo tienes que agregarlo al query que tienes conformado siempre después del ***where***  Ej.

```
@param $campo -> array con el nombre de los campos de las tablas.
@param $value -> string con el valor de que se le va colocar al campo de la base de datos.

//Función para el  filtro SQL.
if(!function_exists('get_search')){

    function get_search($campo, $value){
        if(isset($campo) AND isset($value)){
            //Pasamos el valor de string a array.
            $value =  trim($value);
            $value_array = explode(" ",$value);
            $count = count($campo);
            $c = 1;
            foreach($value_array as $value){
                if($count == 1){
                    $query .= $campo[0]." LIKE '%".$value."%'";
                }else{
                    for($i = 0; $i< $count ; $i++){
                        if($count ==  $i+1){
                            $query .= " OR ".$campo[$i]." LIKE '%".$value."%')"; 
                        }elseif($i == 0){
                            if($c == 1){
                                $query .= " AND ((";    
                            }else{
                                $query .= " OR (";
                            }

                            $query .= " ".$campo[$i]." LIKE '%".$value."%'";
                        }else{
                            $query .= " OR ".$campo[$i]." LIKE '%".$value."%'";
                        }   
                    }

                }
                $c++;
            }
            $query .= " )";
            return $query;

        }else{
            return NULL;
        }       
    }
}
```

> Como usarla:

```
$campo = array('nombre','nombre');
$value = 'casa negra';
$seg_query = get_search($campo,$value);

$query = "Select * From nombre_tabla Where 1 ".$seg_query."";
```

Comment: Perdón solo quiero preguntar porque me marcan negativa la pregunta de esta función si ella realiza la búsqueda  por las dos palabras en cualquier ocurrencia que se encuentre esta función la tengo probada u funciona

Comment: Quizas porque debería ser mas simple.

Comment: No creo que sea esa una razón, si el resultado que se obtiene es el deseado, porque lo que entiendo de que se marca negativa es por que no esta correcto el código o no se ajusta al tema.

Comment: Es una buena implementacion, pero creo que quien te puso negativo lo hizo por que no esta debidamente comentado y para algunos es difícil de comprender a primera vista.

Comment: Muchas gracias y si  escribo un poco difícil el código  para entenderlo de un solo vistazo.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez, en tu código, ¿qué significa o qué función tiene `Where 1 `?

Comment: El uso del **where 1**,  es para poder agregar el **and** el **where** ya que si no lo tengo me envía un error,  por que después del **where** no estoy colocando ningún nombre de campo  sino un **and** directamente y al colocar el 1 no me envía el error.